# Using Mobile Camera on openCV Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, camera

Is there a way to use my mobile phone camera or general mobile e-tab3 camera for my image process openCV-Visual Studio 2013 projects?

Comment: If any device is specifically recognized as `camera` by system, that device can be used. but your mobile phone (i'm not sure) will not be recognized as capturing device (camera)

Comment: btw, opencv is a c++ library. all c# wrappers will be unofficial, 3rd party .

Comment: Yes I know, even my code is c++ I thought I clicked c++ ftfy